# Error JSPDF no exporta correctamente las imagenes

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

Estoy intentanto exportar un div que dentro contiene tablas a pdf con jspdf.
El div y su contenido lo cargo con php.
Este es el div resultante:

```
<div id="test">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="606" style="width:454.2pt;border-collapse:collapse;border:none;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt"> 
    <tbody><tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;height:3.85pt">
                    <td width="90" valign="top" style="width:84.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal">
                <span style="mso-no-proof:yes">
                    <img width="64" height="64" id="_x0000_i1025" src="http://192.168.7.29/html/images/chico64.png">
                </span><o:p></o:p>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="90" valign="top" style="width:71.3pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:
            solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
                <h1>
                0               
                <o:p></o:p></h1>
            </td>
                            <td width="20" valign="top" style="width:15.15pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
                mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
                mso-border-right-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
                height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal"><span times="" new="" '=""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                </td>
                        <td width="90" valign="top" style="width:84.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal">
                <span style="mso-no-proof:yes">
                    <img width="64" height="64" id="_x0000_i1025" src="http://192.168.7.29/html/images/chico64.png">
                </span><o:p></o:p>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="90" valign="top" style="width:71.3pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:
            solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
                <h1>
                1               
                <o:p></o:p></h1>
            </td>
                            <td width="20" valign="top" style="width:15.15pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
                mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
                mso-border-right-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
                height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal"><span times="" new="" '=""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                </td>
                        <td width="90" valign="top" style="width:84.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal">
                <span style="mso-no-proof:yes">
                    <img width="64" height="64" id="_x0000_i1025" src="http://192.168.7.29/html/images/chico64.png">
                </span><o:p></o:p>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="90" valign="top" style="width:71.3pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:
            solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
                <h1>
                2               
                <o:p></o:p></h1>
            </td>

    </tr>
    <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:1;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes;height:3.85pt">
                <td width="179" colspan="2" valign="top" style="width:155.3pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
            padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>
                Jorge Ernesto Fernández de las Heras Arrizabaleta               </o:p></p>
            </td>
                            <td width="20" valign="top" style="width:15.15pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
                mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
                mso-border-right-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
                height:3.85pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
                </td>
                            <td width="179" colspan="2" valign="top" style="width:155.3pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
            padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>
                CAMPO SAEZ DE VITERI, ARRATE                </o:p></p>
            </td>
                            <td width="20" valign="top" style="width:15.15pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
                mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
                mso-border-right-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
                height:3.85pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
                </td>
                            <td width="179" colspan="2" valign="top" style="width:155.3pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
            padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>
                CRESPO CARRERA, MARTIN              </o:p></p>
            </td>

    </tr>
    <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:1;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes;height:3.85pt">
                <td width="179" colspan="2" valign="top" style="width:155.3pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
            padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>
                000532              </o:p></p>
            </td>
                            <td width="20" valign="top" style="width:15.15pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
                mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
                mso-border-right-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
                height:3.85pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
                </td>
                        <td width="179" colspan="2" valign="top" style="width:155.3pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
            padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>
                000822              </o:p></p>
            </td>
                            <td width="20" valign="top" style="width:15.15pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
                mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
                mso-border-right-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
                height:3.85pt">
                    <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
                </td>
                        <td width="179" colspan="2" valign="top" style="width:155.3pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
            border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
            padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:3.85pt">
                <p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>
                001091              </o:p></p>
            </td>
                </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

A pesar de que es una tabla larga tiene un aspecto muy sencillo, tiene tantos estilos para su posterior exportación a Word.

Este es el script:

```
function creaPDF()
{   
console.log($("#test").get(0));
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
    //OR
    //var doc = new jsPDF();

    // We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#test': function(element, renderer){
            return true;
        }
    };

    doc.fromHTML($('#test').get(0), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170, 
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
}
```

En el `console.log` me reconoce el div y su contenido. por lo que no es un error de "encontrar" el elemento html por lo que parece.

Cuando le doy al botón para que me exporte a pdf me aparece este mensaje por consola.

> jspdf.debug.js:7747 jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML!

Este salta en una linea del script de `jspdf.debug` en la que menciona algo de las imagenes:

```
if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(out);else if (found_images) console.error('jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML!');
```

¿Cómo se soluciona este error?¿Si lo hago con `html2canvas.js` cual seria el código correcto?

### Edición

Por lo que he estado leyendo tengo que pasar las imagenes a base64, lo he hecho con php antes de insertarlas de esta manera:

```
$path = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/html/images/chico64.png";
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

Quedan correctamente en base64 y se ven en el html pero a la hora de exportar me vuelve a pasar lo mismo.